# php code to Apply condition in ul tag

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

i have a ul and li list.When i click on the UL List then it expands and collapse...

below is my links inside ul and li tag.

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add Users'), array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'addSubUsers', 'plugin' => false)); ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'listSubUsers', 'plugin' => false)); ?></li>
    </ul>
```

Now i need when i click on the Add Users link the ul tag display like below

```
 <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: block;">
```

**i created below code for this...but this is not working......**

```
 <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Add Users',array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'addSubUsers','plugin' => false),array('id' => 'myId')); ?></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#myId" ).click(function() {
  $(".treeview-menu").css("display":"block");
});
</script>
```

Comment: You'd use javascript for this, not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks For your Help....i done this with php..

```
  <ul class="treeview-menu" <?php echo ($this->params['action'] == 'shipperlist')? 'style="display:block"' : ''?>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add script when click "Add User" id:

```
$( "#adduser" ).click(function() {
  $(".treeview-menu").css("display":"none");
});
```

Comment: did you include the jquery library in your page.?